# Set Blazor WASM base href dynamically with IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, blazor-webassembly, url-rewrite-module

I have a Blazor WASM application created using the standard template. During development, I have been testing the app in the root directory (example page: localhost:5000/login). For production I plan to use URL Rewriting in IIS as a reverse proxy in front of multiple instances of the app that will be running using Kestrel as Windows services. The production URLs will be something like:

http://example.com/Instance1/login rewrites to http://webserver1:5000/login 
http://example.com/Instance2/login rewrites to http://webserver2:5000/login
http://example.com/Instance3/login rewrites to http://webserver3:5000/login

My app works fine if I set the base href for each instance, but is there any way to dynamically change the base href tag so I dont have to change the index.html file on each instance of the application? Is there a better way to accomplish my end result?

Comment: You can set the judgement of InstanceX to instance(.*) so that IIS will accept all requests to instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a working solution for this:

1. Setup URL Rewrite in IIS to add a header that matched the path (using variables from the Regex)
2. Change my static index.html page to a Razor index.cshtml page. Note, when I did this I also had to move the index from the Blazor client application to the server application. Also, don't forget to change the `MapFallbackToFile` call to `MapFallbackToPage`.
3. Add code to the index.cshtml file that checks for the custom header and sets the  `base href` tag.